# How to get the position integer of an item in php array from php to html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to return the position of a topic as well as the topic in a `getTopics()` function. For example, returning "Musical instruments" would also return the integer 0 which can then be used in the `getFaqs()` function. Returning "Programming languages" would also return the integer 1 and so on. I don't understand why this function isn't working as I've included parameters topic_id (the integer) and topic (the text).

**index.html:**

```
function getTopics() {
    $.getJSON("topics.php", function(result) {
        $("#topic-container").html("");
        $.each(result, function(topic_id, topic){
            $("<div>", {id: topic_id , text: topic, onclick: "getFaqs(this.id, $(this).text())"}).appendTo($("#topic-container"));//pass topic_pos 
        });
    });
    return false; 
}
```

**topics.php:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$topics = array("Musical instruments", "Programming languages", "Varieties of pizza");
?>
```

Comment: What are you hoping to magically happen in that PHP?  Maybe `echo json_encode($topics);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [standard `for` loop](http://php.net/for) on the array:

```
var topic, topic_id;
for (topic_id = 0; topic_id < result.length; topic_id++) {
    topic = result[topic_id];
    $("<div>", {id: topic_id , text: topic, onclick: "getFaqs(this.id, $(this).text())"}).appendTo($("#topic-container"));//pass topic_pos
}
```